# Hazelcast throwing exception in spring boot application with vaadin 8 using openfeign

Tags: spring-boot, session, vaadin, hazelcast

We have a web application with Vaadin 8, Spring Boot 2.1.3 and Open Feign.

Now Hazelcast should be integrated for session replication. 
I was following this [article](https://vaadin.com/blog/microservices-high-availability).

The Problem: with Open Feign an exception is thrown in the `InvocationHandler`: `NotSerializableException`, so I implemented my own `InvocationHandlerFactory` setting my own `InvocationHandler` that is implementing the `Serializable` interface.

Now in the `InvocationHandler` the same exception is thrown:

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'org.springframework.session.MapSession'**
    com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'org.springframework.session.MapSession'
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.reflect.Method
```

The problem is: `java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.reflect.Method`

Method is final so it cannot be made serializable.

Is there a way to tell Hazelcast not to try to serialize certain classes?
Any workaround?

I already tried to use the `ApplicationContext` to avoid serialization of open feign classes but it´s not possible because the open feign clients need to be session scoped.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably injecting a Feign client in a UI component, right? If so, the same happened to me when I implemented that example and I solved it by creating the `Services` class you can see in the article. Instead of directly injecting beans that are Feign clients or that have references to them, you can call the static methods in the `Services` class.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I will give it a try if it will return the right instances of the feign clients because our rest backend is stateless so we need to keep the feign clients in the session scope (maybe not the best approach).

Comment: Good. Please share your findings with the community. I'm also interested in the topic.

Comment: I tried it without feign client but ran into similar issues like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611815/how-to-run-hazelcast-session-replication-using-vaadin4spring