# How to run hazelcast session replication using vaadin4spring?

Tags: spring, vaadin, hazelcast, vaadin4spring

I am writing a simple demo application using hazelcast session replication based on the shared security example
mentioned in here https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring.

The problem is that if i am starting the application it stays on the login site with "communication error".
With vaadin debug on, it shows me "Response didn't contain a server id. Please verify that the server is up-to-date and that the response data has not been modified in transmission."

In the IDE no stack trace is shown.

I tried also the working example here https://vaadin.com/blog/microservices-high-availability, but it didn´t give me a hint how to integrate hazelcast with vaadin4spring.

Here is my configuration:

```
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        User.UserBuilder users = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("{noop}user").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable(); // Use Vaadin's built-in CSRF protection instead
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login/**").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/UIDL/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/HEARTBEAT/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.httpBasic().disable();
        http.formLogin().disable();
        // Remember to add the VaadinSessionClosingLogoutHandler
        http.logout().addLogoutHandler(new VaadinSessionClosingLogoutHandler()).logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll();
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"));
        // Instruct Spring Security to use the same RememberMeServices as Vaadin4Spring. Also remember the key.
        //http.rememberMe().rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices()).key("myAppKey");
        // Instruct Spring Security to use the same authentication strategy as Vaadin4Spring
        http.sessionManagement().sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/VAADIN/**");
    }

    /**
     * The {@link AuthenticationManager} must be available as a Spring bean for Vaadin4Spring.
     */
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    /**
     * The {@link SessionAuthenticationStrategy} must be available as a Spring bean for Vaadin4Spring.
     */
    @Bean
    public SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new SessionFixationProtectionStrategy();
    }

    @Bean(name = VaadinSharedSecurityConfiguration.VAADIN_AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS_HANDLER_BEAN)
    VaadinAuthenticationSuccessHandler vaadinAuthenticationSuccessHandler(HttpService httpService,
                                                                          VaadinRedirectStrategy vaadinRedirectStrategy) {
        return new VaadinUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler(httpService, vaadinRedirectStrategy, "/");
    }

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        MapAttributeConfig attributeConfig = new MapAttributeConfig()
                .setName(HazelcastSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE)
                .setExtractor(PrincipalNameExtractor.class.getName());

        Config config = new Config();
        config.setProperty("hazelcast.max.no.heartbeat.seconds", "60")
                .getMapConfig("spring:session:sessions")
                .addMapAttributeConfig(attributeConfig)
                .addMapIndexConfig(new MapIndexConfig(HazelcastSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE, false));
        config.getGroupConfig().setName("admin");

        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    }
```

pom snippet:

```
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>8.7.2</vaadin.version>
        <spring-boot-ext.version>2.0.0.RELEASE</spring-boot-ext.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-hazelcast</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.spring.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-ext-boot</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-ext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.spring.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-ext-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-ext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.spring.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-ext-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-ext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```